# Open Edge Progress database update query

Tags: database, openedge, insert-update, progress-4gl

I'm a beginner in Open Edge Progress database.

Is there any query to update/insert data into progress database table

my try was

```
ASSIGN
  TABLE.COLUMN=DATA
END
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to access a record:

```
FIND TABLE WHERE TABLE.FIELD = 42 EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
```

or

```
FIND FIRST TABLE EXCLUSIVE-LOCK.
```

or create a record:

```
CREATE TABLE.
```

You're assign statement is missing a period (.) to terminate the statement - and you don't need an END statement unless you're opening a block somewhere.

```
ASSIGN TABLE.COLUMN=DATA.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have one more query, could you please tell me is there any way to execute this query from command prompt

Comment: You need to save that into a procedure file (test.p) and execute _progres -p test.p or something similar.